# What is a flameout and how does it occur?

Tags: jet-engine, engine

I often hear the word "flameout". What is this and how does it occur?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flameout basically means that the flame in the combustion chamber has been extinguished. A jet engine compresses air, then adds fuel and ignites it. So, it needs three things to function correctly- fuel, air (oxygen), and the heat to make them burn. [Removing any of the three can cause a flameout](http://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/flameout-9043856/?no-ist).

It can happen for a number of reasons:

- fuel starvation- [Air Canada Flight 143](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimli_Glider) suffered flameout (due to wrong amount of fuel being put) and had to be landed like a glider.
- Compressor stall (or surge)- The disruption of airflow due to compressor stall can cause an engine flameout.
- Ingestion of foreign objects - [British Airways Flight 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Airways_Flight_9) suffered flameouts in all four engines due to ingestion of volcanic ash
- Firing of armament- Early in its service A-10 Warthog suffered flameouts due to the engines ingesting the gassed generated while firing the GAU-8 Avenger.

Early jet engines (like the Jumo 004B) had [high rates of flameout](http://www.stormbirds.com/project/technical/technical_3.htm); however, modern jet engine flame outs are very rare, at the rate of about one every 100,000 non military flights. In most cases of flameout, the [engines are restarted](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB120753185285993925) for resumption of flight.

---

[Airspace magazine](http://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/flameout-9043856/?no-ist) mentions a case where flameout happened because a F-100 ingested fuel (during aerial refueling); however, such occurrences are quite rare.